# html email template and justified text

Tags: html, outlook, justify

I've got an html email template (using table hell) with the resulting email looking fine in gmail and outlook 2003. In outlook 2007, the text is however not justified (instead it's left justified). Is there a work around for this?

The relevant code used:

```
<td style="text-align: justify;">
```

doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the code for the email?

Comment: Yes, I thought I put in the relevant code, but it has been disappeared.
The relevant part:
<code>
<td style="text-align: justify;">
</code>


doctype:
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might be a bug in Outlook 2007.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=1149

There isn't really a workaround either I'm afraid; it's probably just not possible.

Comment: Thanks, I expected just an odd quirk of outlook 2007. I'm surprised they broke it altogether compared to 2003.

Answer (score 1):

It is Microsoft making our jobs easier and their customers user experience supreme. Obviously.

Also try `style=" float:left;"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td style="text-align:justify !important;">
<p style="your style, but don`t use text-align declaration in here">
Lorem ipsum
</p>
</td
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floats on emails, several email clients doesn't support it.